# Install Ansible on a Mac or rather on an Ubuntu VM?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, mac-osx, ansible

Using MacOS as my primary machine, I would like to use Ansible.

Glancing over tutorials I get the impression that running Ansible from Ubuntu (or in my case: a dedicated virtual machine running Ubuntu) will be more practical than installing and running it on my Mac. Although the installation on a Mac is easy (via `pip install` or `brew install`, I need extra configuration to make paths work. On an Ubuntu machine I would have to specify the hosts / remote machines in `/etc/ansible/hosts`. On my Mac I would have to do extra steps.

So my question: Does it make sense to create a dedicated VM for running Ansible? Or is it fairly easy to run it from my Mac directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd run it from a Ubuntu VM. If you use `connection: local` or `delegate_to: localhost` you will be executing on the Mac or Ubuntu VM. Even with homebrew, the Mac userland can be interesting, to say the least, with ancient versions of software. For example I was (unwittingly) using macos's version of `tail` and was surprised by its lack of features. (Homebrew's version is called `gtail` to avoid naming conflict.)

If you do choose to use the Mac, I'd at least use a python virtual environment (anaconda, pyenv, etc) to handle the miriad of python modules used by ansible without version conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it's any more work to run it from a Mac than Ubuntu. Maybe I am missing something.

You mention `/etc/ansible/hosts`, but that isn't necessary for a single-user control node. That would be useful if you have a shared control node where other users will leverage the same inventory.

Even then, you could put the Ansible configuration, inventory file, and Playbooks in a single directory under version control. Each user could clone the repository and run it from their local systems.